# Ionic with laravel as backend concept

Tags: laravel, api, http, ionic-framework

I'm confused because i've heard that we create an api using Laravel and could use Ionic to call the api and access the database. As Laravel and Ionic are created in a separate folder, do we have to publish both of them online? I mean if i just publish ionic, then how does ionic communicate with Laravel when Laravel isn't being publish ? and if so,it means we have develop both an app and a website right ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would have IONIC as a mobile application calling your RESTAPI (Laravel) through AJAX.
Think about it as two separate projects. IONIC is your frontend and Laravel is your backend.

Ideally your API would be published on the same level as your IONIC app. If you are planning to use your IONIC app only on a local network then the API have to be published on that local network. If you are planning to use your IONIC app on the "internet" then your API should be published to internet access.

On a side note: Wherever you publish your API you should strongly consider [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) to protect you API.

I also recommend reading [Fielding's REST Paper](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) to have better understanding about REST.

Comment: so this means that if i want to publish my app online, then i would have to publish the laravel API. Publishing laravel also in other words means publishing a website. Just the website will be empty and serve as an API only for ionic to consume correct ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It is going to be a "website" which accepts HTTP calls in JSON/XML format an returns JSON/XML.

Comment: Thanks. a lot clearer now

Comment: That's good to see! You're welcome.